# Comparison of TeX editors with respect to collaboration (diff etc)

Tags: editors

I am attempting to read my student's LaTeX file and leave suggestion/corrections.    This is for Win7 and a file of about 100 pages.
At a minimum I expect to compare two files and/or show changes with a different color. Which TeX editors are most suitable for this task?

Comment: Not an editor, but perhaps ['latexdiff'](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) is of interest.

Comment: For any diff viewing, I like `meld`. For leaving notes in documents, you may like package `todonotes`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well emacs of course:-) (M-x ediff to show diffs)

[image]

Comment: Emacs. Of course.

Comment: Boo! ❤ But I upvoted it. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Not sure why you say "Boo" ? I thought you were a big fan of the font.

Comment: @David: Comic Sans? Of course. `:)`

Answer (score 16):

There's a tool called [latexdiff](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) which highlights differences between 2 tex files. You call it this way:

```
latexdiff [ OPTIONS ] old.tex new.tex > diff.tex
```

And then you run `pdflatex` on `diff.tex` and you will get a new `pdf` file which highlights changes in the document (quite similar to the review option in MS Word).

**Later edit:** If you wish to compare source files (e.g. `.tex`) then any decent version control software (`git`, `svn` etc) provides a `diff` tool for this purpose.

Answer (score 7):

As of two days ago the online TeX editor [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/) has added change tracking to its features. Especially nice is that since it is online and requires you to have an account, it will automatically identify the user who enters the comment.

[Here](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2014/03/31/track-changes-in-your-latex-documents.html#.Uzx24V60ZXM) is a link to their blog post explaining the new feature.

It does have some limitations, though. See [the big IDE list question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116794/17835) for some more info.

Comment: I haven't tried very long files (more than 30-40 page PDF), though, so can't say how compilation times would be impacted if the thesis was all a single .tex. Hopefully, though, it isn't just one long .tex file.

Answer (score 1):

Another editor is [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) where you can set up LaTeX compilation fairly easy with packages [LaTeXTools](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/LaTeXTools) or [LaTeXing](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/LaTeXing) and have diff functionality in a variety of ways with

- [Glue](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/glue) A package allowing to access your OS console, so you directly run commands like `svn diff`.
- [FileDiffs](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/FileDiffs) A package allowing to diff different files or sections of files.

Also, there are a lot of packages for integration of version control like `svn` and `git` a simple search in the [package control](https://sublime.wbond.net/) repository can unravel a lot of them though I have not personally tried.